# can't use function return value in write context - error in line 7

Tags: php

I can't understand what is the issue.
I know this question is repeated but not able to understand what is the issue in my code.

```
<?php
//REVIEW BOX DISPLAY
function sch_ninja_display_review($postcontent){
    global $post;
    $review=$post;
    if(get_post_meta($review->ID,'review_show',true)=="on"){
       if(!empty(get_post_meta($review->ID,'review_price',true))){
          $price='Price:'.get_post_meta($review->ID,'review_currency',true).get_post_meta($review->ID,'review_price',true);
       }
```

Line 7:  if(!empty(get_post_meta($review->ID,'review_price',true))){

Comment: what is the problem? (apart from missing `}` at the end)

Comment: @Jeff make that 2 `}`

Comment: @jeff & suraj Do you have knowledge of php, without braces not getting such kind of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`empty()` is a PHP language construct and only supports variables and expressions, and no function calls as arguments.

You will have to assign the result of your call to a variable first and then do the empty check like so:

```
$reviewPrice = get_post_meta($review->ID,'review_price',true);
if(!empty($reviewPrice)){
```